# Multiple reveal modal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Multiple reveal modal is not working. Example, 
I have 2 screens, If I click reset button one reveal popup is open. without closing that popup if i open another screen and open one more reveal modal, the previous screen reveal modal is hided. Both screen has having same class name for reveal modal. I have to use same class name. But different pages. How can resolve this issue?

My requirement is, if I open multiple pages also all reveal modal should be display properly without hiding.

Please Check the below fiddle. It is only one page. Same as If I have another page it will create a problem.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqog0y5b/4/)

```js
$(document).foundation();

$('a.open-first').on('click', function () {
  $('#first-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
    multiple_opened: true
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='second-modal' class='reveal-modal' data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  I'm the secondborn!
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="first-modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  I'm the firstborn!
  <a href="#" data-reveal-id="second-modal">Modal in a modal&hellip;</a>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<a class='open-first'>Click me!</a>
```

Comment: Add `foundation` to your question - tag to get better views to your question.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am using foundation.js and css file.

Comment: what does "open another screen" mean here, a new browser window?  Seems to be working OK?